# Cooling just one mode?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, cooling

In the context of Brillouin scattering and Stokes/anti-Stokes scattering in a silicon waveguide, a speaker mentioned optical cooling, but apparently only cooling a single "mode" was cooled. I had never heard of cooling only a particular mode before, and I cannot tell for sure if it was an electromagnetic mode or a vibrational mode that was cooled. A vibrational mode makes more sense, but I have not found discussion of either poking around google. Either way, wouldn't the cooled mode eventually take heat from the rest of the system and cool everything down? If not, is it really cooling at all?

I would be very grateful for an explanation of how "cooling a single mode" can be meaningful.